# Change Windows 10 resolution in Hyper-V 2.0 to match windows size

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, resolution, hyper-v

I've been using VMWare for a while and swapped over to Hyper-V recently and am having a frustration where resizing the Hyper-V window does not change the resolution of the VM. Instead I get scrollbars on the right and left, which kills the usability of the device.

I need this as I drag the connection window to different resolution screens depending on my task, and disconnecting and reconnecting to the VM every time to change the resolution (And only to the allowable presets...) is very tedious.

How can I get the VM to update it's display resolution to match the connection windows size?

Comment: This is a question for your RDP client.  The desktop resolution can be changed, and VM's can be set to do this automatically to match the window, but the client has to report to the VM that you changed the window size.

Comment: I suppose it's using the provided RDP client in windows? I'm connecting to the VM directly by double clicking on it in the manager.

Comment: Maybe check if the integration Services are enabled in Hyper-V

Comment: @Peter They are.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell What machine is running the manager?  What application does the manager use to display the VM?  It's hard to advise you on how to set up your client when we do not have full information on what client you're using.  Once you find out the client, search for configuration options.  Assuming you're on a Windows client of some sort, there's probably some kind of registry setting where you can customize the size to your satisfaction or allow for dynamic desktop resizing.

Comment: This this a Gen1 or Gen2 VM? Also,is enhanced session enabled?

Comment: @Peter This is a Gen 2 VM with enhanced session enabled.